# Adding Google Analytics Tracking To BigCommerce App Store Listing

Tags: html, google-analytics, bigcommerce, event-tracking

I have an app on the BigCommerce app store. I'm trying to set up conversions on Google Analytics, and I need to install my tracking code to the app store. I need to do this because users are bouncing off the app store portal before installing my app.

The url I am directing people too via my own site is:

https://apps.bigcommerce.com/details/85

Is there anyway to add the tracking code to this via BigCommerce's dev portal? Or does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The BigCommerce Marketplace doesn't currently support GA tracking (or any third party tracking scripts).

We're working on building out more tracking and insights for our app partners though, so keep an eye out in the future for access to that kind of data.